# Splitting field for an irreducible polynomial which is not separable

Tags: abstract-algebra

Note that some infinite field of finite 
characterisitc, like ${\bf Z}_2(t)$, has an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ which is not separable. For instance $f(x)=x^2-t$. 
  Here I have an question

> Question :  On an infinite field $F$ of finite 
>   characteristic, splitting field $K$ for an irreducible polynomial which is not separable is isomorphic to $F$ ?

This is wrong ? or right ?

In above example, splitting field is ${\bf Z}_2(\sqrt{t})$ which is isomorphic to ${\bf Z}_2(t)$.

And splitting field $K$ for $x^3-t$ on $F={\bf Z}_3(t)$ has $$ x^3-t=(x-\sqrt[3]{t})(x+2\sqrt[3]{t})^2 $$ So $K={\bf Z}_3(\sqrt[3]{t})$ which is isomorphic to $ F$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbf{Z}_2(\sqrt{t})=\mathbf{Z}_2(t)$? They are isomorphic as fields but not equal to each other. We can think of $\mathbf{Z}_2(\sqrt{t})$ as a degree two field extension of $\mathbf{Z}_2(t)$, though.

Comment: @ Jyrki : I means an isomorphism : $\sqrt{t}\mapsto t$. And I will edit.

Comment: So by "is itself" in your question you actually mean "is isomorphic to F"?

Comment: @ sea : Yes, it is $F$. I eddited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following is a counterexample. Let $F=\mathbf{Z}_2(t)$ as earlier. Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^4+x^2+t^3\in F[x]$. If $z$ is one of its zeros, then $y=z^2$ is a zero of the separable irreducible polynomial $g(x)=x^2+x+t^3$. The other zero of $g(x)$ is easily seen to be $y+1$, so $F[y]$ is the splitting field of $g(x)$, and $F[y]/F$ is a Galois extension.

So  $z$ and $z+1$ are the zeros of $f(x)$ - both of multiplicity two. The splitting field of $f$ is thus $F[z]$. This is not isomorphic to $F$. There are probably several ways of seeing this. The first one that comes to mind is probably unnecessarily advanced. Namely we see that $F[z]$ has $F[y]$ as a subfield. And we can identify $F[y]$ as the function field of the elliptic curve $y^2+y=t^3$, which has genus $1$ and thus cannot be isomorphic to a rational function such as $F$. OTOH, if $F[z]$ were isomorphic to $F$, then by Lüroth's theorem its subfield $F[y]$ would also be a genus zero function field.

Comment: Sorry about going via the high-brow route of elliptic curves and Lüroth. Hopefully somebody can come up with an example that requires less background.

Comment: Anyway, if $f(x)\in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial, then the splitting field of $f(x^2)$ always works, I think. Need some coffee.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. In fact my question is trivial. If inseparable extension $K$ is isomorphic to $F$ then extension is useless. But if we have algbraic extension $F\subset E_{sep} \subset K$ of finite degree, where $E_{sep}$ is separable extension (sometimes $E_{sep}$ is not isomorphic to $F$, as you said), then $E_{sep}$ is isomorphic to $K$ ?